# In a general solution to the differential equation, are each of the individual terms continuous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given some complete general solution to an Nth order differential equation:

$$y(x) = c_1f_1(x) + c_2f_2(x) + c_3f_3(x) + c_4f_4(x) + ... c_n f_n(x)$$

Must each of the terms $f_i(x)$ be continuous? If so, could you please explain why? I wish to use certain methods of solving differential equations (by finding a piece wise constant $c_n$ that makes y continuous after a faulty integral), which rely upon the fact that all of the (n-1)TH derivatives of y are continuous (because then I have n linear equations), but if each of the terms are all that need to be continuous then it is much easier to solve.

Comment: Yes, because each one is a solution to the DE separately, so they are each at least $C^n$.

Comment: Just be warned that I'm assuming these are strong solutions, so that for instance you don't have bad behavior like delta function forcing or something like this. In this case your (weak) solution may have less regularity.

Comment: If your equation is of the form $L(t,y,y',\dots,y^{(N)})=f(t)$ where $L$ is linear in all of its arguments (except possibly $t$) and $f$ is continuous, then what I said is correct. You have a problem if, for instance, you have that form with $f(t)=\delta(t)$.

Comment: Oh, duh, yes, right. Then yes, provided your coefficients are continuous then what I said is fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here, can you fill in some details? In particular, is the equation actually linear or no?

Comment: To be just continuous, no, but I think that if your coefficients are piecewise continuous and their singularities are just jumps, then at worst you will lose continuity of the $n$th derivative. In this case you will still have $C^{n-1}$, which it sounds like is what you need. (Note that when I said "coefficients", I meant "coefficients in the equation", i.e. your equation would be $\sum_i a_i(t) y^{(i)}(t) = f(t)$, where $a_i(t)$ are continuous functions.)

Comment: You can have additional problems with zeros in the leading coefficient, but otherwise yes, I think that's correct.

Comment: Severe singularities like blowups. (For example, some of the Bessel functions have such singularities at $r=0$.)

Comment: Vertical asymptotes yes.

Comment: It can happen any time the leading coefficient has a zero.

Comment: I'm thinking of things like $xy'+y=0$ where the time domain is $[-1,1]$. This one can be explicitly solved: $\frac{d}{dx}[xy]=0,xy=C$. So either $y$ is identically zero or else $y=\frac{C}{x}$ for $C \neq 0$, which can't be continuous. Yet all the coefficients are clearly continuous. The problem here, as put in the differential equations text used at my university, is that this equation is not given in "normal form". The normal form has a leading coefficient of $1$, and transformation to normal form quickly reveals the problem.

Comment: If you have a linear equation in normal form (i.e. the leading coefficient is $1$) and the coefficients are continuous, then the solutions are $C^n$. If you have a linear equation in normal form and the coefficients are continuous but at least locally bounded, then the solutions should be at least $C^{n-1}$. If you have a linear equation in normal form with locally unbounded coefficients then you may have serious regularity problems, as $y'+\frac{1}{x}y=0$ demonstrates.

Comment: Typo in the last comment: "continuous but at least locally bounded" should be "not continuous but at least locally bounded". Anyway, I will write an actual answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say a linear $n$th order ODE is in normal form if it is written:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i(t) y^{(i)}(t) + y^{(n)}(t) = f(t)$$

i.e. the leading coefficient is $1$. When all the $a_i$ are continuous and $f$ is continuous, a strong solution exists and in particular is $C^n$. If the $a_i$ are not continuous but are locally bounded and have only jump discontinuities, then a weak solution exists and is $C^{n-1}$. More serious problems can arise when the coefficients are not locally bounded. (I'm not sure what happens if the $a_i$ have essential discontinuities.)

These problems are most easily exemplified by the equation

$$y'+\frac{1}{x}y=0$$

whose nontrivial solutions all blow up at $x=0$. This equation is a good example of why we have to consider the normal form, because one can write this as $xy'+y=0$, in which form the coefficients are continuous.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck All of them; they are all solutions and here the problem is with locations in t not locations in y.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Any reason you unaccepted?